# How do I filter out certain words taken from a HTTP website?

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine

I'm making this simple script that checks app version and server version. If different, it'll prompt the user to download. Since I don't have a server, I hope to host it free online using this website: https://xto8doxt.app-adstxt.dev/app-ads.txt

I have this script:

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(ServerAddress);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

RemoteVersion = www.downloadHandler.text;
Debug.Log(RemoteVersion);

if (Application.version == RemoteVersion)
{
    JforceEntertainmentLogo.SetActive(true);
    ShowUpdateMessage.SetActive(false);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

Let's say the application version is 1.0.0 and on the website it is this:

```
lovely served by https://app-adstxt.dev/ -- free app-ads.txt hosting
2.2.7
```

Is there any way to filter out the `lovely served by https://app-adstxt.dev/ -- free app-ads.txt hosting` from my script? I only want to compare the app version from the server and my app only.

Comment: Find the last space. Look only at text **after** the last space.

Comment: @mjwills just that the last is no space but a linebreak ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for the text you have you could

1. [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split) it on the linebreak
2. use the second line (index 1)
3. optionally use [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) to remove leading and trailing whitespaces

so e.g.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(ServerAddress);
yield return www.SendWebRequest();

var content = www.downloadHandler.text;

var lines = content.Split('\n');
RemoteVersion = lines[1].Trim();
```

so `RemoteVersion` should now be `"2.2.7"`